# Best approach on allowing users create their own fields

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm about to embark on a project where a user will be able to create their own custom fields. MY QUESTION - what's the best approach for something like this?

Use case: we have medical records with attributes like first_name, last_name etc... However we also want a user to be able to log into their account and create custom fields.  For instance they may want to create a field called 'second_phone' etc...   They will then map their CRM to their fields within this app so they can import their data.

I'm thinking on creating tables like 'field_sets (has_many fields)', 'fields', 'field_values' etc...

This seems like it would be somewhat common hence why I thought I would first ask for opinions and/or existing examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is where some modern schemaless databases can help you. My favourite is [MongoDB](http://mongodb.org). In short: you take whatever data you have and stuff a document with it. No hard thinking required.

If, however, you are in relational land, [EAV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity-attribute-value_model) is one of classic approaches.

I have also seen people do these things:

- predefine some "optional" fields in the schema and use them if necessary.
- serialize this optional data to string (using JSON, for example) and write it to text blob.

Comment: Nice thanks Sergei.  I would like to use MongoDB - however, in this case am required to use relational.  Going to look into your rec'd deeper to get some ideas.